# Representing logical operations in math/logical notation.

Tags: logic, notation, computer-science, pi

I want to use notation like [this for loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fc80a.png) (which was used in an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1240700/representing-several-if-statements-inside-a-for-loop-in-math-notation)) for some code I have written to calculate the "solar time" of a timestamp given it's location and time of year.

I'm doing some animal circadian activity research and animals change their activity with the sun (and moon, some of the time), but because sunrise and sunset change over the course of a year and at different latitudes it is useful to convert 24 hour time to a proxy value which is kind of the location of the sun throughout the day, standardized to a 0 to 2π interval with sunrise at π/2 and sunset at 3π/2.

Here's the [actual code](https://github.com/canderson318/Tapir-Research/blob/main/some%20circadian%20scripts/convertTimeToSolarTime.R); it works like this:

- `rise` is the sunrise, and `set` the sunset at that time a latitude.
- `hour` is the timestamp of the animal sighting
- `solar` is the sun-time scaled to the nearest solar event (sunrise and sunset)

```
if (hour <= rise):
  solar = pi/2 * hour/rise #predawn

elseif (hour <= set):
  solar = {(hour - rise) / (set - rise)} * pi + pi/2 #daylight

else:
  solar = {(hour - set) / (2pi - set)} * pi/2 + 3pi/2 #postdusk
```

It would be great if this could be written succinctly for a publication I am working on to show what "solar time" is without having all of the code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 1) You have a $p/2$ in your second formula ; isn't it $\pi/2$ ? 2) Is your question about grouping in a way or another the 3 formulas into a single one ? But what for ? There are many instances of functions defined "by intervals" with "ad hoc" formulas.

Comment: I am trying to convey this logical operation as a simple equation.

Comment: Is piecewise notation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise) what you're looking for?

Comment: i believe what you are looking for is a piecewise function.

Comment: That looks right, thanks!